# redirecting page with error codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, error-handling

I'm working on uploading a profile picture and I'm trying to figure out how to redirect the page while passing data to it. For example if there is an error in the upload I would like to pass that message into the redirect.

I was trying something like this

```
$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());    
redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $error);
```

and then in my view just printing out the error

```
<?if(isset($error)){
   echo $error
}?>
```

I'm not getting back an error or anything, just the same view. Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Comment: The second parameter of the `redirect()` function in CodeIgniter does not take an error message to display. It takes the method of the redirect (refresh or location): This is what flashdata is used for: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: I was looking at flash data before. I was a bit confused how to use it though. Would I set the flash data to the error and then redirect or would the redirect be part of the flash data?

Comment: The flash data is stored in the session. You would set the flash data, then redirect, then read the flash data on the page you redirected to.

Comment: I guess what I'm stuck on is reading that flash data. I have it set and then redirecting, but do I pass that data into the page as an array like I would a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the place that you get your error:

```
//get the errors
$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
//set the errors to the flash data
$this->session->set_flashdata($error);
//redirect
redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

On the page you redirected to:

```
//get the errors
$error = $this->session->flashdata('error');
//do something with your errors
if(!empty($error)){
    echo '<pre>';var_dump($error);echo '</pre>';
}
```

Hope this gets you pointed in the right direction ...